# Can you automatically auto-select and join teams upon server entry?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I don't care what team I end up on, I just want to get into a game as fast as possible. Is there a **config toggle** that will *never* ask me which team and always just use auto-select?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such thing client-side, but server mods do exist to this effect (well, at least for TF2). If you're a regular on any particular server you could talk the owner into enabling such a mod.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is to just press enter twice. There is no such **config toggle**.